# How to abort compilation in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio

I'm using TeXstudio to compile my LaTeX code. However, for some reason in my code, the compilation will be immersed in a endless loop. Hence, when I fix the problems in my code (or may be not) and need to recompile it, I have to kill the engine first. What's more annoying, if the problem that causes the never-ending loop remains, I have to kill the process in terminal window again and again and again.

Is there any way to abort compilation in TeXstudio?

Comment: What kind of OS are you using? Linux or MacOS?

Comment: @Ch'enMeng Thank you for your comment. I'm using Linux. Why?

Comment: Since I was a TeXstudio user under Linux and Windows, I know how to abort the compilation in TeXstudio---by pressing `Esc`, however, I'm not sure if this will work under MacOS. Try it. :)

Comment: Since 2.7 release there is an icon on menu with this feature (red color during compilation).

Answer (score 18):

You can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to terminate the process in TeXstudio.

Comment: Is there a method to unbind the `Esc` key from canceling the compilation? During compilation I often want to close some dialog and reflexively hit `Esc`, aborting the compilation.