# Aborting a compilation in Texmaker

Tags: compiling, texmaker, cancel

Well, I've read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148640/how-to-abort-compilation-in-texstudio), but doesn't solve the problem for Texmaker, and I'm really clumsy, instantly seeing errors after a tedious long time wrong compilation.
As I really don't expect any self-improvement from my persona:

Is it a way to kill the compilation in this one?

Comment: With the "Messages/Log"  pannel enabled, you can find a small button with a cross on it. This button turns red while compiling.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ7Mw.png 8might look different is you have a newer version of texmaker)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you activate the `Messages/Log` window, you will see the following buttons on left.
[image]
The button which I indicatied is `Stop Process` button. You can press this button when compiling.